# Visual Studio 2013 adds Debug and Release directories to solution explorer after each build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Each time i build my solution(c++), and restart visual studio, those directories keep reappearing in my solution explorer tree, is there a way to make it stop?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- In your Project properties, Build (right click on project file in solution explorer), check the build folder : is it where you want ? You can generate your build on other paths if you wish. Remember : the build folder depends of currently selected build profile so you may have to change it for more than one.
- Also, the folders like bin, obj, debug, release... are normally hidden. They will be visible (with a white icon) if "Show all files" button (on top of solution explorer) is toggled on. Therefore, as long as these folders are not included in the solution, you can hide them by toggle off "Show all files"